# Trying to play large audio files with Pygame Mixer (Mac OS)

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-mixer

Whenever I try to run pygame.mixer_music.load('myfile.mp3') with big audio files, it tells me that `pygame.error: mpg123_getformat: Failed to find valid MPEG data within limit on resync. (code 28)`

This only happens with big audio files, I can play small ones just fine

Comment: Treat the large audio file like a stream. Load in some bytes and play them. While that is happening load in some more bytes and queue them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

For starters I think you need to add the full path of your mp3 file. For example:

```
pygame.mixer_music.load('/home/pi/Desktop/myfile.mp3')
```